# Motion Sensor control on a carport light, with "over-ride" or "reversing" action from a 2 or 3 way light switch

Tags: motion-sensor

This project is to create a "security" system to light up the carport anytime someone enters or drives into the carport, but also with the ability to be remotely turned on for security suspicions or on/off for convenience use.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Unfortunately, "shopping" questions are off-topic here. Please [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: I won't vote to close bc there seems to be a simple solution. Run a switch leg in parallel with the motion sensor. to the desired location. Turning on the switch would turn on the lights, turning it off would return control to the motion sensor.

Comment: What precise *function* do you want out of the light switches, and where do you want the motion sensor to live?

Comment: many motion detector fixtures allow you to briefly turn the switch off then back on to force it on bright.

Comment: @dandavis  nailed it:  go to a good  (large) electrical supply or  home improvement store and buy the kind of  motion detector which supports this  "double-click" behavior

Comment: @DanielGriscom  I read the question as asking  how - or if -- a solution exists, not "what product should I buy" question.

Comment: I don’t think this is a purchase question but a how to.  I agree with George.

Comment: Are you OK with piece-parting this out of "smart" parts or commercial-style low-voltage lighting controls, by the way?  Or are you after some sort of "turn key" solution to this issue that you can buy at your local home improvement store?

Answer (score 2):

You really need to go with smart switches/sensors and a smart light -- **the kind that gives you a simple programming language so you can define how each sensor and switch action behaves.** That way you can program exactly the effect you want for each of the large variety of conditions.

You're creating a lot more combinations of potential conditions *than you think you are*.  Just to name a few:

- Light off, sensor detected motion, light on.  User threw switch.  Now what?
- The above happened and now after 1 minute there is motion again.
- Motion sensor detects motion.  User operates switch within 1 second.  Is this commanding the motion sensor off, or did user see/hear same thing?
- Motion sensor times out, and turns light off. User operates switch within 1 second.  Is this a command to turn the light back on?
- Light is turned on 6 hours ago because of manual command and it is now daylight.

The usual blunder here is doing the minimum wiring necessary to make the various items connect, and then expecting the assembly to do *exactly what a butler would do*.  They won't.

If you want to keep it simple, just have 2 lights - one under control of the switches, one with the motion sensor.

Comment: The other option I can see being workable here would be to use commercial-style low voltage motion sensors and control switches...

Comment: Not sure why the down vote so reversing it.

Comment: @EdBeal Thanks. I'd guess somebody didn't like bad news, or thought Code was stupid.  I get flamed all the time on diychatroom for sticking to Code.

Comment: Any time I notice a - without a reason I reverse it , well if it is really obvious maybe not but there is nothing worse than taking time to help and getting a downvote without a reason.

Answer (score 1):

I have motion lights with 3 sensors that turn lights on I also have an over ride that turns the lights on using a simple 3 way switch 1 position uses the sensors the other powers the lights directly if I want to work on it it needs to be turned off at the breaker (I later did add another switch to kill the power) .